# Structures & Functions , feval() | MA

Tags: matlab

I have a structure in workspace like this

```
structIn =
      name: 'add2AndSquare'
    inputs: {[2]  [1]  [7]  [5]  [3]}
     lines: {'x = in + 2',  'out = x.^2'}
```

I need to do this :

1) Create a function  .m  file in the current directory using Low-Level File I/O.

Write a function header. The header will always be written to have one input
called "in" , and one output from the function called "out" .

Write each string from the cell array stored in the  lines field into the new  .m file.

Make sure to suppress the outputs of each line, and don't forget the new line
characters!

Don’tforget to put an'end'at the end of the file!Close the file handle once you're done writing.

2) Create a new field in the structure called  outputs that contains the corresponding results of running the newly created function on each element stored in inputs .

In order to run your function once it is written, you will need to use a very cool MATLAB function called feval() .

result = feval('', ) 
simply calculates the output of running the function with the name ' '(as a string) on the input <  inputToFunction> .

For example,  feval('sum', [2 3 4]) outputs the value  9.

3) Delete the  lines  field from the structure since it is no longer needed.

```
 structOut =
          name: 'add2AndSquare'
        inputs: {[2],  [1],  [7],  [5],  [3]}
       outputs: {[16],  [9],  [81],  [49],  [25]}
```

Please Help me on this. !!

Comment: This exercise seems completely pointless to me. Who creates an exercise like this?

Comment: @Bernhard Unfortunately the lab instructor does this kind of things. Do I have any help on this.